# Variance of an integral of a product of functions with Gaussian distributions

Tags: variance, gaussian-process

Let
\begin{align} 
I(t) = K \int_{-T/2}^{T/2} e^{i 2\pi f_X \left(t + X(t) \right)}
\cos\,(2\pi f_Y (t + Y(t)) - \phi))\,dt,
\end{align}
where $X, Y$ are independent random variables which are the function of time $t$ and have Gaussian distribution $X \equiv N(\mu_X, \sigma^2_X)$ and $Y \equiv N(\mu_Y, \sigma^2_Y)$. All other parameters are constants.

How I can find the variance of $I(t)$ without knowing the covariance (i.e., $Cov(I(t_1), I(t_2))$ = unknown).

Comment: what is $Y(t)$? is that supposed to be like a Gaussian process?

Comment: Yes, both $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ are independent Gaussian processes.